# KnockoutJS click data bind not working when used with with binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

What I'm trying to do is to hide an html when a flag, selected, is true.  Which I was able to do via click data bind and below works great.

```
<a href='#' data-bind='click: selected, with: myObject, visible: !selected()'>
    test
</a>
```

While above works as I intended it to be, below doesn't work.

```
<a href='#' data-bind='click: selected, with: myObject, visible: !selected()'>
    <div>test</div>
</a>
```

I have tried changing 'a' to 'div' but that still didn't work.  Can somebody help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I misunderstood what you were struggling with.

The problem is that `with` only applies to child nodes. So, you need a wrapper around the `<a>` tag in order to apply the `with` binding.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3qMq/1/)

Comment: Have you tried running your fiddle where 'click:selected' instead of 'click:whenClicked'?  Because that works

Comment: True, it does. But then, what's your question?

Comment: Click binding doesn't work when parent dom is defined with "with" binding and text is wrapped in another dom as above.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I misunderstood the point of your question.

Comment: Hmm. Your fiddle works but for some reason it doesn't work in my code.  Code that is closer to what I have can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/L3qMq/2/.  Is there like depth limit or something? because this logic is located pretty deep

Comment: A `<div>` can't legally be the child of an `<a>` so it's possible the browser isn't building the DOM you think it is.

Comment: @CodingTwinky. There is no intrinsic depth limit that I have seen while working through the knockout code (I am a user, not an author, but I have had to spend more than a little time in the source). Do you get a stack overflow, out of memory, and sort of error in the console window? If you hit a limit, either knockout or the browser should complain. We have significantly nested, multiply-composed views in our application with no limits hit.